# Original Proof of Riesz-Thorin

Tags: reference-request, math-history, interpolation

Wikipedia says that Riesz proved the Riesz-Thorin theorem in 1926 without using any complex methods.  Does anyone know where the original proof can be found?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem

Comment: This may be a useful reference for historical purposes:

http://books.google.com/books?id=wd864jh25DQC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=original+proof+of+riesz+thorin+theorem&source=bl&ots=mv0u0u_fqG&sig=vxx_iBW-qH8S0aRFAF4JzpxELMQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5mGYUP7bAo680QHqo4CYBQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=original%20proof%20of%20riesz%20thorin%20theorem&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia seems to be wrong about the year. The full reference is:

Marcel Riesz: *Sur les maxima des formes bilineaires et sur les fonctionelles lineaires*. Acta Mathematica, Vol. 49 (1927), pp. 465-497.

It can also be found in M. Riesz's [Collected Papers](http://books.google.no/books?id=FKb8wL3gUKIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=no#v=onepage&q&f=false).